# ScrollView logic to scroll to bottom is only going to the second-to-last element

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm making a quick little app for some teachers, and they asked that this `ScrollView` automatically shows the last element whenever the list extends beyond the screen.

Here's the code I implemented to do so:

```
void ScrollDown()
{
    View lastChild = container.GetChildAt(container.ChildCount - 1);
    int bottom = lastChild.Bottom + scroll.PaddingBottom;
    int sy = scroll.ScrollY;
    int sh = scroll.Height;
    int delta = bottom - (sy + sh);
    scroll.SmoothScrollTo(0, lastChild.Bottom);
}
```

In the image below, you can see that it only scrolls partway down the screen. I'm not sure what I'm missing here, any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Here is is my main view containing the `ScrollView`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:text="Student Name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView1" />
        <EditText
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/studentName" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
            <Button
                android:text="Start Observing"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/observationButton"
                android:layout_margin="10sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px">
            <Button
                android:text="Incident Start"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/incidentButton"
                android:layout_margin="10sp"
                android:layout_height="100sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5sp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/container"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can try scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)

Comment: So, I read in another thread that `scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN) ` steals focus, and that's something I want to avoid. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Actually, I just tried this `scroll.FullScroll(FocusSearchDirection.Down);` and it's doing the same thing! I wonder if it's something to do with margins?

Comment: how about scroll.smoothScrollTo(lastChild.Left, lastChild.Top)?

Comment: Same thing, very strange.

Comment: The only issue i can see with the above code is that you're not taking into account the current scroll position and use relative scrollBy() instead of scrollTo, but that should overscroll, not scroll less. Or maybe it overscrolls and bounces back.

Comment: You can try adding lastChild.MarginTop + lastChild.MarginBottom to the delta if they're not 0 but I doubt it will make a difference

Comment: This behavior might be caused by additional measurements and layouts  of the scrollview after the call to scroll.scrollBy is executed. If the other views (buttons) in the layout change height and your ScrollView dimensions are altered it will change bounds and even if it retains initial scroll position it may not be exactly at the bottom. You can put some breakpoints in the onMeasure() / layout() or add some layout change listener for the scroll to see when it changes relative to the scrollBy call

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a really good solution, but first I had a mistake.

My `ScrollView` has only one child, `container`. So counting this children of `scroll` was pointless.

What I did instead was this:

```
        container.LayoutChange += delegate
        {
            ScrollDown();
        };

        void ScrollDown()
        {           
        scroll.SmoothScrollTo(0, container.Bottom + 30);
        }
```